# returns a new dynamically-allocated C string containing every second character of s starting with the first one

Tags: c

Here is my code I think I nearly got that but there are some small mistake

```
char* skipping(const char *s) {
    int length = strlen(s);
    int newLength = length/2 + length%2;
    int pointers = 0;
    char* buff = malloc(newLength + 1);

    for ( int i = 0; i < length; i++ ){
        if (i%2 == 0){
            buff[pointers] = s[i];
            pointers++;
            }
    }
    return buff;
    buff[pointers] = '\0'; 

}   

int main()
{
    char* s = skipping("0123456789");
    printf("%s\n", s);
    free(s);
}
```

I expect 02468, but what I got is 02468\x93\xd7. I don't understand what happened. Any suggestion would be appreciated :).

Comment: add the null character to buff before you return buff..

Comment: Your `return buff` is before your nullchar set line, which becomes useless. Turn up your compiler warnings; it should have pointed this out.

Comment: so you mean put buff[pointers] = '\0';  before return buff;   ?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I fixed it.  That is a dumb mistake.

Answer (score 2):

If you `return` before a line of code the code wont get executed and the `'\0'` doesn t get appended

Switch both lines

```
return buff;
buff[pointers] = '\0';
```

to

```
buff[pointers] = '\0'; 
return buff;
```

and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

You close the buffer after returning:

```
return buff;
buff[pointers] = '\0';
```

It should be:

```
buff[pointers] = '\0'; 
return buff;
```

Surely there were some compiler warnings and you have ignored them.

Consider also to simplify your code. Study this:

```
char *skipping(const char *s)
{
    int length = strlen(s);
    char *buff = malloc(length/2 + 1);

    int pointers = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i+=2)
    {
        buff[pointers] = s[i];
        pointers++;
    }
    buff[pointers] = '\0';
    return buff;
}

int main()
{
    char *s = skipping("0123456789");
    printf("%s\n", s);
    free(s);
}
```

Comment: Suggestion: `int length = strlen(s);` --> `size_t length = strlen(s);`. Also, it would be better if you check `malloc`'s return value.